# Show that $xy = (x|y)|(x|y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

Show that:
$$xy = (x|y)|(x|y)$$

I could get back from $(x|y)|(x|y)$ to $xy$, however, I can't seem to get it the other way around. This also looks a bit similar with $\neg x = x|x$. Is there a way to get from $xy$ to $(x|y)|(x|y)$?

Edit:
$$(x|y)|(x|y)$$
$p|q = \neg(pq)$
$$\neg(xy)|\neg(xy)$$
$$\neg(\neg(xy)\neg(xy))$$
$pp = p$
$$\neg(\neg(xy))$$
$\neg \neg p = p$
$$xy$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you got back from $(x|y)|(x|y)$ to $xy$?

Comment: @Henry I just did. Thanks

Comment: I think I can just trace back from the end $xy$ to the start $(x|y)|(x|y)$. Thanks a lot @Henry

Comment: Yes - if each line is equivalent to the next then you could simple reverse the order of your statements